# Image with text on the right without using css

Tags: html, css

I'm using an old itext to create a pdf, and I'm making an pdf paragraph with HTMLWorker and I can't use CSS.

I've tried using float and I can't also.

I need an image with right text with the less html code possible.

Now i have this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src='http://losmercadosfinancieros.es/wp-content/uploads/world-globe1.jpg' width='100' height='100'>
        <h1 style='color: green;'>Heading in Green</h1>
        <div style='color: red;'>Sample text in red color.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Text should be right image

Comment: _"...and I can't use CSS."_, but you are using css

Comment: @AlonEitan use less CSS possible, this library don't allow some styles like float.

Comment: try `text-align`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` **is not** suitable for website layouts but I think it's good for PDF like your case.

```html
<table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="120">
      <img src="//losmercadosfinancieros.es/wp-content/uploads/world-globe1.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </td>
    <td width="680" valign="top">
      <h1 style="color: green;">Heading in Green</h1>
      <div style="color: red;">Sample text in red color.</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the plain-old `align` attribute of the image?

```html
    <img src='http://losmercadosfinancieros.es/wp-content/uploads/world-globe1.jpg' width='100' height='100' align="left">
    <h1 style='color: green;'>Heading in Green</h1>
    <div style='color: red;'>Sample text in red color.</div>
```

Comment: Not working... Thanks anyway. I think I can only use this: https://www.kencochrane.net/blog/2008/03/itext-htmlworker-style-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is as per your requirements...
I tried in online Editor its working fine for me.
If its not as per requirement pls do mention req. clearly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        img {
        float:left;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <html>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <img src='http://losmercadosfinancieros.es/wp-content/uploads/world-globe1.jpg' width='100' height='100'>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1 style='color: green;'>Heading in Green</h1>
                </div>
                <div style='color: red;'>Sample text in red color.</div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src='http://losmercadosfinancieros.es/wp-content/uploads/world-globe1.jpg' 
     width='100' 
     height='100' 
     style="float:right">
```